# Sql One to many join and count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables one is requests and other is states , request tables stores all the incoming requests ,state of incoming request are mapped one to many from request table to state table .each request have client id for identifying who is created that ticket .

How can i get count of request in each state for each clients .

HOW  can i get get each user how many states are zero count

```
    select count(1),state,c.client_id
from Client c join Request r on r.client_id = c.client_id
group by r.state,c.client_id order by c.client_id desc
```

This query not having states with zero count

table structure is given below.

***Client***

1. client_id
2. client_name
3. location
4. email_id
5. address

***Request***

1. request_id
2. client_id
3. subject
4. description
5. state_id
6. created_time

***Request_state***

1. state_id
2. state_name

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen postgress

Comment: Even if you haven't tried something, you should at least edit your question and show a table of what you want your expected output to look like.  I don't even think this is answerable right now.

Comment: sir , i stuck with this question , what i want is a report out put for all clients having how many requests in each state , my problem is state table have many rows .. want to find count of that type in request

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Please read how to ask question before asking next one :)

Comment: @VaoTsun sorry .. i will improve

Comment: sure thing. did you get your answer?

Comment: @VaoTsun that two answers are correct but state count 0 is not there

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select count(1),state_id, client_id
from Client c
join Request r on r.client_id = c.client_id
group by 
state_id, client_id
```

**update**:
As op was expecting a row with count = 0, it can be reached with:

```
with c as (
    select count(1),state_id, client_id
    from Client c
    join Request r on r.client_id = c.client_id
    group by 
    state_id, client_id
)
select * 
from c
union all
select 0,null,null
;
```

Comment: if count is  zero it means there are no such rows - what fo you expect to then?..

Comment: expected result is there should be a a row having count 0

Comment: then append to the end: `union all select 0, null,null`