# Sql One to many join and count including zero

Tags: sql

I have two tables one is requests and other is states, request tables stores all the incoming requests, state of the incoming request are mapped one to many from request table to state table. Each request has client id for identifying who has created that ticket.

How can I get a count of the request in each state for each client?

HOW  can I get each user how many states are zero count

```
    select count(1),state,c.client_id
from Client c join Request r on r.client_id = c.client_id
group by r.state,c.client_id order by c.client_id desc
```

This query not having states with zero count

table structure is given below.

***Client***

1. client_id
2. client_name
3. location
4. email_id
5. address

***Request***

1. request_id
2. client_id
3. subject
4. description
5. state
6. created_time

***Request_state***

1. state_id
2. state_name

**Table and Data**

[image: Output]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907603/sql-one-to-many-join-and-count/43907708

Comment: @VaoTsun there your answer is wrong , that query you added only add one row having zero , i want to include each users states that having 0 count ,

Comment: I'm not saying it is right :) Just providing more information on your post, maybe my bad example will help others

Comment: "I have two tables".  How come your code has different tables?  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sir plz tell me

Comment: @VaoTsun that is current answer but for me want to include little more

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text! Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh I will add now

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer